# Regular expression for number and word next to number javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, words

If I have this string

```
If you eat 5 cookies you'll consume 200 calories
```

I need a regular expression which can extract `5 cookies` and `200 calories`
In simple words I want a regular expression in java script which can extract numbers and word next to number

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use

```
'If you eat 5 cookies you\'ll consume 200 calories'.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?\s\w+/g)
```

- \d+ - digits
- \s - a space after the digits
- \w+ - some set of characters after the digits

Demo: [RegEx](http://regexr.com/3b0f8)

Comment: Thank you..!
But I want to use this regular expression for numbers
var rxp = new RegExp("(([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)|([0-9]+))", "gm");

Answer (score 0):

If your text will always have the form `If you eat <count_of> <something> you'll consume <some> calories`, the you can use the regex below

```
var regex = /^If you eat (\d+) (\w+) you'll consume (\d+) calories$/;
```

The second, third, and third matches will be the one that will interest you (the first match is the actual string).

If you want to capture the ( ) together instead of capturing into two separate matches, you can replace `(\d+) (\w+)` by `(\d+ \w+)`.

Comment: Thank you..! But I have to use this regular expression for numbers var rxp = new RegExp("(([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)|([0-9]+))", "gm");
Also text will not always have this form

Comment: `I have to sue this regular expression` as in `I'm allowed to use only this` or as in `This better suits my needs`?